# Leave intact specific section of page when using Angular Snap

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular [Snap](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js) module but I can't make it only use a section of my page. For example I want yo leave header and footer intact when "snaping".

The follow example code describe my issue http://plnkr.co/edit/qOilojtXpCcBm99ynuzQ?p=preview

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-snap.css" type="text/css" />
         <script src="snap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
         <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.4"></script> 
         <script src="angular-snap.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

         <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body  ng-controller="MainCtrl">

   <!-- Header Image should here -->
   <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>

   <!-- Menu Bar goes here -->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu-holder">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a class="test" href="#">This is the one</a>

                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- menu-holder end -->
</div>

    <!-- Both Snap-drawer and Snap-content should go below the Menu bar -->
  <snap-drawer>
   <button snap-toggle>Another Toggle Button</button>
   </snap-drawer>

    <snap-content snap-options="{tapToClose:false}">
     <button snap-toggle>Toggle</button>   
      </snap-content>


  </body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Plugin creator gives me answer for this on https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js/issues/75

I copy answer here for Archive purpose:

> It's doable, here's an example with a fixed footer from a previous
>   thread, Snap still applies to the whole page we're just showing
>   content over it:
>
> http://plnkr.co/edit/Vdz0AZ3tnlfErERmjcrY?p=preview
>
> You can change it to a fixed header by updating the nav element like
>   so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"  style="background:red">
    <div class="container">
      Bottom container stuff!
    </div> 
</nav>
```

> Just fair warning there are [some issues](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/issues/79) with using fixed position
>   elements, just something to keep in mind.
>
> The snap-content directive should expand to fill it's container, so
>   you may also be able to get something working by wrapping that element
>   in a non-static positioned element. [Here's a rough demo](http://jsbin.com/soqenu/1).